Implementing eBay Developer API for Listing Products - Receiving 500 Error on Multiple API Calls
I'm working on integrating my eCommerce site with eBay's Developer Program to list products on a user's eBay UK account. I'm using Node.js and Axios to handle API requests. However, I'm encountering a 500 Internal Server Error on multiple API calls, particularly when trying to fetch category suggestions, inventory locations, and create various policies.
Here’s a simplified version of the API calls that are causing issues:
async createInventoryLocation(): Promise<any> {
  const accessToken = await this.getAccessToken();

  try {
    const InventoryLocation = {
      location: {
        address: {
          addressLine1: "221B Baker Street",
          addressLine2: "Marylebone",
          city: "London",
          stateOrProvince: "Greater London",
          postalCode: "NW1 6XE",
          country: "GB", // UK country code
        },
      },
      locationInstructions: "Items ship from here.",
      name: "Warehouse1",
      phone: "+44-20-7946-0958", // UK phone number format
      merchantLocationStatus: "ENABLED",
      locationTypes: ["WAREHOUSE"],
    };

    const response = await axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: `${EBAY_BASE_URL}/sell/inventory/v1/location`, // Corrected URL
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      data: InventoryLocation,
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to create inventory location:", error.message);
    throw error;
  }
}


I’ve already verified that:
The accessToken is valid and retrieved successfully.
The URLs being used are correct and match the documentation.
The headers are set according to the eBay API guidelines.
Despite this, the server responds with a 500 Internal Server Error. The error message doesn't provide much insight into what might be going wrong.
Things I've tried:
Verified the API endpoint URLs and parameters.
Checked the JSON structure of the request body for POST requests.
Reviewed the eBay API documentation to ensure proper usage.
Has anyone encountered similar issues with the eBay Developer API? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this error or what might be causing it?
